# How to access a query parameter ("$_GET") in mod_python?

Tags: python, wsgi, mod-python, query-string

I want to know how to show requests (`$_GET`) on a python script ?

Note that i am using `mod_python` as basic web server running with apache2 on UBUNTU server.

If you have any idea your help will be very appreciated :)

Other python web server like Django etc ... note needed in my case because i am running only one python script for a specific task :)

Comment: Are you using any web frameworks or are you drinking from the WSGI hosepipe directly?

Comment: No i don't use any framework :) basic python web server :)

Comment: Then start using one now. There is little reason to stay at that low level. Pick one from https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks, although Flask, Pyramid and Django are most popular right now depending on your needs.

Comment: For a specific, simple task without a database backend use Flask.

Comment: Then with basic web server no way to do it ?

Comment: Sure there is, but why go through that pain at all? If you insist, at least read a [WSGI tutorial](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial).

Comment: Because i need it only for one script :) i am using web site coded on PHP :)

Comment: @user3818090 Consider a small micro-framework (running in mod_python) to provide very basic access such as this. There is much to take advantage of without needing to use models/views/controllers (eg. something big and opinionated like Django) if not desired.

Comment: I think like suggested,  WSGI will resolve this problem :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a simple script to respond to a web request, I'd not use `mod_python`; you probably want to switch to `mod_wsgi` instead here.

You'll have to parse the `QUERY_STRING` WSGI variable yourself; you can do so with the [`urlparse.parse_qs()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

def application(environ, start_response):
    params = parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
    foo = params.get('foo', [None])[0]
```

`parse_qs` parses out the query string and sets the value in the resulting dictionary to a *list* per key, because keys can occur more than once in a query string.

The above will pick out the first value in the list, or `None` if the key isn't present at all.

If you are going to stick to plain-vanilla WSGI, read a [decent tutorial](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial) to understand how it works. I strongly recommend you use a framework however; even just [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/) can make your life as a developer vastly simpler, even for a simple script.

If you are going to stick with a `mod_python` request handler, replace `environ['QUERY_STRING']` with [`request.args()`](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pythonapi.html#apache.request.args):

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

def requesthandler(req):
    params = parse_qs(req.args)
    foo = params.get('foo', [None])[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, and how to call `def application` 'foo' from an external string ?

Comment: @user3818090: ick, you are using `mod_python`, not `mod_wsgi`. That's rather ancient and outmoded these days..

Comment: I just installed `mod_wsgi` like you suggested me !

Comment: @user3818090: ah, then I'll roll back to the other revision. `mod_wsgi` is certainly the better choice unless you want to write a Apache filter or connection handler.

Comment: Ok thank you, i want use it inside `def index():` :)

Comment: I get this error when using your code: `NameError: global name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: @user3818090: my mistake, I meant to use `req` (the argument to the handler).